# libsignal-protocol-javascript outdated/alternateive

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on an chat-web-app and I have trouble to find good Encryption Libraries for js. Till I found out about the [libsignal-protocol-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com) . But it is old and seems to no work properly.
Is there a good or at least a updated alternative/version.

This is a piece of an example that I gave tried to get working:

```
<head>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='libsignal-protocol-javascript.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='InMemorySignalProtocolStore.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script>
    var KeyHelper = libsignal.KeyHelper;

    function generateIdentity(store) {
        return Promise.all([
            KeyHelper.generateIdentityKeyPair(),
            KeyHelper.generateRegistrationId(),
        ]).then(function (result) {
            store.put('identityKey', result[0]);
            store.put('registrationId', result[1]);
        });
    }

    function generatePreKeyBundle(store, preKeyId, signedPreKeyId) {
        return Promise.all([
            store.getIdentityKeyPair(),
            store.getLocalRegistrationId()
        ]).then(function (result) {
            var identity = result[0];
            var registrationId = result[1];

            return Promise.all([
                KeyHelper.generatePreKey(preKeyId),
                KeyHelper.generateSignedPreKey(identity, signedPreKeyId),
            ]).then(function (keys) {
                var preKey = keys[0]
                var signedPreKey = keys[1];

                store.storePreKey(preKeyId, preKey.keyPair);
                store.storeSignedPreKey(signedPreKeyId, signedPreKey.keyPair);

                return {
                    identityKey: identity.pubKey,
                    registrationId: registrationId,
                    preKey: {
                        keyId: preKeyId,
                        publicKey: preKey.keyPair.pubKey
                    },
                    signedPreKey: {
                        keyId: signedPreKeyId,
                        publicKey: signedPreKey.keyPair.pubKey,
                        signature: signedPreKey.signature
                    }
                };
            });
        });
    }

    var ALICE_ADDRESS = new libsignal.SignalProtocolAddress("xxxxxxxxx", 1);
    var BOB_ADDRESS = new libsignal.SignalProtocolAddress("yyyyyyyyyyyyy", 1);

    var aliceStore = new libsignal.SignalProtocolStore(); // Here does it fail

    var bobStore = new libsignal.SignalProtocolStore(); // And heere
```

Every time I run it it throws this error:
Uncaught TypeError: libsignal.SignalProtocolStore is not a constructor

But it is also not a function. I am sure that I Overseeing something. But I could not figure out what.
And I feel not well to use this old project. Maybe through the fact that it does not receive updates since 6 - 8 years, I could get some minus points for using it. But if there is no alternative and I could get it working, I would use it.